# serve mp4 and pdf files using php script

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, pdf, mp4

How can I protect pdf and mp4 files with php script? When I type the exact url of a file in my uploads directory in wordpress I am redirected through .htaccess to a php script (serve.php) that should be able to serve the content of the pdf and mp4 files to the authenticated users only. The script should check the if the user is authenticated and then check if the file is pdf or mp4, then serve the content and the appropriate headers.
Thanks :)

Comment: Anyone?? Come on friends I really need this...

Answer (score 0):

Once you have sent your file to `serve.php`, as per the previous question, you'll need to simply check that the user is logged in (authenticated).

If the user is not authenticated, you should simply throw an error message stating that they are not allowed to view the file, using `die()` or outputting a message with a `403 Forbidden` HTTP status code using `header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');`.

Comment: Hey Mike, I have already done this. The main problem arise when it comes to serving the files to the authenticated users. I want to play mp4 with my flowplayer and render the pdf with my pdf reader. Should I redirect them or should I do thet through the headers? Any odeas?

Comment: That's for a completely different question. If the user is authenticated, the file that serves the data can simply render the output (using FlowPlayer, or your PDF reader, for instance). Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

If your server has x_sendfile apache module - try it.

[mod_xsendfile homepage](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/)

How to use:

[PHP - Protecting digital Downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412328/php-protecting-digital-downloads)